# If $\angle BCD=90^0$ and $\displaystyle \cot \angle ACB=\frac{3}{10}$ and $\displaystyle \cot \angle ADB=\frac{1}{2}$ , then $h=$

Tags: geometry

$AB$ is a tower standing in a horizontal plane, $B$ being its foot; $C$ and $D$ are two points in the plane .

such that $\angle BCD=90^0$ and $CD=4$ mete. It is found that $\displaystyle \cot \angle ACB=\frac{3}{10}$ and $\displaystyle \cot \angle ADB=\frac{1}{2}$.

The Height of the Tower is

Please explain to me using a diagram if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no picture. But a picture is necessary.

Let $h$ be the height of the tower. Note that $AB$ is perpendicular to $BC$ (unless, of course, the tower is a **Leaning Tower**).

So $\dfrac{BC}{h}=\dfrac{3}{10}$ ("adjacent divided by opposite"), and therefore $BC=\dfrac{3h}{10}$.

Similarly, $BD=\dfrac{h}{2}$.

But by the Pythagorean Theorem, $BC^2+CD^2=BD^2$. So $BC^2+16=BD^2$.

It follows that $\dfrac{9h^2}{100}+16=\dfrac{h^2}{4}$.

Thus $\left(\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{9}{100}\right)h^2=16$.

This simplifies to $\dfrac{16}{100}h^2=16$. Now $h$ is easy to find.